# Java executor: Submitting a batch of tasks?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Here's what I want to achieve:
I want to have some object (probably an executor of some sort) to which I can submit a "batch" of tasks to be executed (say `List<Callable<T>>`). When all of these tasks have finished running I want to be notified (probably through a value available in a `Future` object).

This "executor" should be able to handle several batches at once. In other words: two (or more) code sites can submit two different batches and each of these sites will be notified only when "his" batch is over.

Even better, I want that `Future` to provide me with a `List<T>` holding the values that were returned by the various tasks (`Callable`s).

Summarizing the above I am looking for something that offers an API that is conceptually identical to:

```
public T Future<List<T>> submitBatch(List<Callable<T>> tasks)
```

What canned constructs from `java.util.concurrent` can help me the most in achieving that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `ExecutorService` has [just the method for that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

And it (nearly) fits your demands, since it returns a `List<Future<T>>`.

Therefore:

```
final List<Future<Whatever>> list = service.invokeAll(myCallables);
// walk list and call .get() on each future
```

Note that as the doc says, this method will wait until all callables are done. Also, you still need to check for failures in each `Future`.